# Invert edges in a directed graph (transpose graph) in igraph (R packages)

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

suppose I have given an igraph graph in R and want to invert all edges:

[image: Transpose_graph]

see [Transpose graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_graph)

```
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)
g <- make_star(n=6)
plot(g)
gt <- transposeGraph(g) # hypothetical function
plot(gt)
```

One way seems to be to rebuild the graph, but I am concerned about the performance and the loss of vertex attributes:

```
gt <- graph_from_data_frame(as_data_frame(g) %>% select(to, from))
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am currently running the following code as it preserves all node and edge attributes.

```r
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union

g <- make_star(n=6)
V(g)$name <- LETTERS[1:6]
E(g)$weight <- 1:5
plot(g)
```

[image]

```r
transposeGraph <- function(g){
  gDf <- as_data_frame(g, what = "both")
  graph_from_data_frame(gDf$edges[,c(2:1, 3:ncol(gDf$edges))], directed = T, gDf$vertices)
}

gt <- transposeGraph(g)

plot(gt)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A possible answer can be found [here](https://rdrr.io/github/robertness/lucy/src/R/misc-utilities.R), however it doesn't keep the vertices attributes.
It should be possible to restore attributes using `get.vertex.attribute` and `set.vertex.attribute`

Try:

```
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)

g <- make_star(n=6)
plot(g)
```

[image]

```
transposeGraph <- function(g) {
  g %>% get.edgelist %>%
    {cbind(.[, 2], .[, 1])} %>%
    graph.edgelist
}

gt <- transposeGraph(g)
plot(gt)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Performance comparison shows that it's about 10x faster on a 100 vertices star:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                                         expr      min        lq     mean   median
 graph_from_data_frame(as_data_frame(g) %>% select(to, from)) 4300.308 4495.1795 4844.328 4654.769
                                            transposeGraph(g)  315.487  350.5645  457.711  404.308
       uq       max neval cld
 4806.770 13324.719   100   b
  437.539  4488.205   100  a
```

Comment: Can you explain, why you think this would have a better performance?

Comment: I'm not sure this has a better performance but it seems difficult to make leaner. Best way to know is to create a bigger random graph and to test both solutions with `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(transposeGraph_dataframe_solution(g),transposeGraph_igraph_solution(g))`.

Comment: A related answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63016581/13513328

Comment: @c0bra, did you have the opportunity to make a performance comparison on your dataset?

Answer (score 1):

With R/igraph 1.3.3 or later, you can use the `reverse_edges()` function. This function preserves all attributes, and alows allows for reversing only some edges.

An alias for reversing all edges is `t()` (for "transpose").

Answer (score 0):

Solution discussed here are failing if the graph contains isolates.

```
library(igraph)
tGraph <- function(g)
          { g %>% get.edgelist %>% {cbind(.[, 2], .[, 1])} %>% graph.edgelist}
g <- make_graph(c(1,2,4,5)) + 1
gt <- tGraph(g)
gtt <- tGraph(gt)

isomorphic(g, gtt)
[1] FALSE
identical_graphs(g, gtt)
[1] FALSE
```

The code below preserves isolates and graph attributes.

```
t.graph <- function(g){
tg <- add_edges(delete_edges(g, edges=E(g))
     , t(get.edgelist(g, names=FALSE)[,2:1])) # revert edges
edge_attr(tg) <- edge_attr(g)                 # save edge attributes                                               
return(tg)
}

g <- make_graph(c(1,2,4,5)) + 1
gtt <- t.graph(t.graph(g))

isomorphic(g, gtt)
[1] TRUE
identical_graphs(g, gtt)
[1] TRUE
```

Note that unlike graph_from_edgelist, add_edges needs a vertex sequence which is a transposed edgelist.